# Searching a text file for an int value Python

Tags: python, search, int

Let's say I have a text file of integers separated by spaces (eg 1 4 6 27 189...)
and I have in my python code a variable (let's call it 'num'). What do I use if I want to read the text file to check if num is already included as an integer in the text file? Eg if num = 27, then it would return a positive because 27 is already in there. What I don't want, however, is let's say num = 18, it to return positive because of the 18 in **18**9. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    print(str(num) in f.read().split())
```

`f.read()` is the string contents of the file.

`f.read().split()` is a list of the numbers as strings. `.split()` splits on spaces. Because they're strings, we convert `num` to a string with `str(num)`.

Comment: sorry, i tryed your code and the return are outside from the function .

Comment: @SkillerDz I used return because it was mentioned in the question, but it's not necessary.